# How to program ESP8266 with Arduino Uno pins 0 and 1?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I know that I can connect an ESP8266 with an Arduino Uno at pins 0 and 1, which is Rx and Tx, and enter commands manually in the serial monitor the commands to test it.

I had tried to use software serial and altserial to connect an ESP8266 to other pins, but it was error prone at sometimes.

My question is that how to use an automated program to control an ESP8266 when I connect the ESP8266 with an Arduino Uno at pins 0 and 1.

Sample code would be helpful.

Edit: I have added a simple program to blink led when it get response but it is not working. could you look at it too?

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(3000);
  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("AT");
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);

    while(Serial.available())
    {
      char c=Serial.read();
    }

    delay(2000);
  }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here using esp8266 and arduino? You said connecting using software serial was error prone. What do you mean? Were you getting junk values in the serial monitor? or something else.. please be specific. There could be a lot of issues related to power supplied or the buad rate or even loose connections...

Comment: Remember that the TX pin on the arduino puts out 5v logic levels, while the ESP8266 require 3.3v logic level. You can create a buffer using a simple diode (cathode on the Arduino TX pin, anode on the ESP RX pin)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using pins 0 and 1 is that they are also used to communicate with the PC for both serial monitoring *and* programming.

If you attach an ESP8266 to pins 0 and 1 chances are you will fail when uploading a new sketch - you will have to disconnect the ESP8266 every time you need to upload a new sketch - that is why most people use SoftwareSerial.

Also if you are using pins 0 and 1 for the ESP8266 you cannot then also use the serial monitor to see what is going on with your program and thus be able to debug it when it's not working.

If you're OK with both those caveats then by all means go ahead and use pins 0 and 1.  You use it in exactly the same way as using SoftwareSerial but you don't need to define an object first - you just use the pre-defined Serial object.

One important thing to remember with the ESP8266 is that the default firmware's AT command interface is ropey as hell.  It's most likely that which is tripping you up not your SoftwareSerial.  You have to get the timing right with it from what I remember - always impose a 1 second delay after sending each command - it's the delay that terminates the command, not a carriage return (although I think a CR is also needed). Maybe later versions have been improved since, but that's one really good reason to directly program the ESP8266 and implement your own protocol for communicating.  My [ICSC](https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/ICSC) library is a good candidate for communicating between the two - it runs on both the ESP8266 and the Arduino.

Comment: I tried a simple program to send AT commands via serial which is connected to esp8266. I added an led to blink when i got the response so that i could know it is working. But the led is not blinking.

Comment: i have added it in the question.

Comment: @abdulrahuman You're program is expecting a response from the ESP module before the serial command has had a change to get there and be processed. Your whole serial reading methodology is flawed.

Comment: could you please be specific about where in the program should I change. I am beginner. A sample code could help better.

Comment: @abdulrahuman http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/reading-serial-on-the-arduino

Comment: Nice article majenko. Now I think i got what I am missing. I will try it and give you results. Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried your program. But it didn't work. It gave the same results as before

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Arduino IDE serial Monitor Window for ESP8266 setup instead of using TTL or Serial Converters. I successfully Setup My ESP8266 Module by using just Arduino Nano and Arduino IDE Serial Monitor.

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial softSerial(3, 2); // RX, TX

void setup() 
{
  uint32_t baud = 9600;
  Serial.begin(baud);
  softSerial.begin(baud);
  Serial.print("SETUP!! @");
  Serial.println(baud);
}

void loop() 
{
    while(softSerial.available() > 0) 
    {
      char a = softSerial.read();
      if(a == '\0')
        continue;
      if(a != '\r' && a != '\n' && (a < 32))
        continue;
      Serial.print(a);
    }

    while(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      char a = Serial.read();
      Serial.write(a);
      softSerial.write(a);
    }
}
```

[image]

[Necessary AT Commands](http://www.electronicslovers.com/2017/11/learn-how-to-setup-wifi-module-esp8266.html)

[image]